# Are clam and nautilus antivirus working propperly?

Tags: antivirus

When I installed any of those I can't  run or even find them. Since then I can't use any of my internet browsers, I would love to delete them. Any suggest how? Thanks

Comment: sorry but I had to down vote this question as there are many duplicates if you had just put a minimum afford in searching. next time place your question on google search and if you find no answer then you can post your question in forums like askubuntu. thx

Comment: Nautilus AntiVirus? I've never heard of that. You mean clam-nautilus (ClamAV)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove them with the same exact way you installed them.

For example if you want to remove the tool called "foo" from command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove foo
```

or alternatively you can either use ubuntu software centre or synaptic (gui based tools) all you have to do is to scroll between tool until you find the one you are looking for (or you can use search as well), then right click and remove.

Nautilus is file explorer, not sure how that would block you in your internet navigation. I can say the same for clam, never heard that it block internet connection unless you haven't specifically put the rules in configuration file.

if you don't have enough knowledge about certain tools it is better not to install them at all.

Here a step by step guide about how to remove tools:

```
http://www.howtogeek.com/197919/how-to-easily-add-and-remove-programs-in-ubuntu-14.04/
```